WhatsApp Video Resending Stuck on iPhone
I am facing a problem when sending videos to multiple people on my iPhone. When I try to resend videos from WhatsApp to several contacts, the sending process gets stuck and doesn't complete unless I lock and unlock the phone screen.
I have tried many solutions to resolve the issue, including:
Deleting and reinstalling WhatsApp.
Resetting the network settings.
Resetting all settings on the phone.
Ensuring that background app refresh is enabled.
Verifying that there is enough storage space on the device.
Updating the operating system to the latest version.
Performing a factory reset on the phone.
Reinstalling the operating system via iTunes.
However, the problem persists.
Please note that the videos I am trying to resend are videos that I originally received on WhatsApp.
